# how to have regular user to use port 80 on ubuntu?

Tags: services

I am login as a regular user on ubuntu server, and I need to start up a service at port 80. As of now, it does not allow me to do that, as it is reserved for admin users.

But I do see a same type of user on another ubuntu server, that have the service started and is using port 80. I want to have the current user set up to reach the same behavior, but I am clueless what should I do ? I have the full control of this ubuntu server.

here is my service current status on that server:

```
systemctl -l status  gns3.service
● gns3.service - GNS3 server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gns3.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2022-03-23 16:57:07 UTC; 4s ago
    Process: 78994 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/log/gns3 /var/run/gns3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 79003 ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R gns3:gns3 /var/log/gns3 /var/run/gns3 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 79007 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/gns3server --log /var/log/gns3/gns3.log (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 79007 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

And here is what the in the service log file:

```
tail -10 /var/log/gns3/gns3.log
2022-03-23 17:13:13 INFO run.py:224 Config file /etc/gns3/gns3_server.conf loaded
2022-03-23 17:13:13 INFO run.py:243 Running with Python 3.8.10 and has PID 82762
2022-03-23 17:13:13 INFO run.py:79 Current locale is en_US.UTF-8
2022-03-23 17:13:13 INFO web_server.py:318 Starting server on 0.0.0.0:80
2022-03-23 17:13:13 INFO __init__.py:63 Load controller configuration file /etc/gns3/gns3_controller.conf
2022-03-23 17:13:13 INFO __init__.py:67 Controller is starting
2022-03-23 17:13:13 INFO compute.py:64 Create compute local
2022-03-23 17:13:13 INFO compute.py:364 Connecting to compute 'local'
2022-03-23 17:13:13 WARNING compute.py:367 Cannot connect to compute 'local': Cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1:80 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 80)]
2022-03-23 17:13:13 CRITICAL web_server.py:88 Could not start the server: [Errno 13] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 80): permission denied
```

This system is built on top of ubuntu 20.4 image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ports under 1024 (1000?) are reserved for root configuration and roots server processes. You won't be able run a server process on ports less than 1024 (1000?) without root intervention.

You can however start a server process on any port over 1000/1024 as a regular user, though this probably won't help you except for maybe as testing.

Also, you're aware that port 80 is usually reserved for the web server process correct?

Hope you have enough information now.

Comment: Thank you. Your information is very generic and useful.  But this time this service is very special and I want to check if it matters if it is of port 80, or other value, when it is trying to connect to the downstream clients.

Comment: when you say downstream client i find that to mean the return connection., which in most most cases cannot be controlled. but due to the the very useful and generic question i find that i can make do.

Comment: I revisited this again today with new eyes and made some interesting observations.2022-03-23 17:13:13 WARNING compute.py:367 Cannot connect to compute 'local': Cannot connect to host 127.0.0.1:80 ssl:default [Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 80)]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution in another thread. So just in case someone may have the similar issue, here is the details:

1. my service is running gns3server, which is of python code.
2. In run time, it is using "/usr/bin/python3.8" to have the actual service triggered.
3. So in order to have "python3.8" to be able to use port 80, I need to run this command as root:

   sudo setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip /usr/bin/python3.8
4. Then have my ubuntu server rebooted.

Once it is back up, I have found my service is up and running at port 80 without any issue.